# How to Change main menu color?

Tags: css, styling

i have a issue with menu that i cant change text color in mini fixed meni in this [site](http://deil.cz/)

I tryed to add this CSS to custom CSS:

```
.classic-menu .menu-item a {
  color: #000;
}
```

but when set color to #000 then color in main menu is turn black. So i want color in main menu to be white in black background, and in mini fixed menu when scroll down, to be white background with black font color. How to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is the mini-fixed menu? I don't see any fixed menu on that page.

Comment: Oh I think you mean the main navigation menu...does 'mini' mean on mobile. BTW, this site looks awesome.

Comment: Hi mini menu i called fixed menu that is shown when you scroll to bottom in that page. Please scroll down, and will see the issue.

Comment: use `color:#000 !important`

Comment: Yes i tryed that, but take a look on main menu from top. Menu items color was turn to black, and in black background in not see nothing. For that i need main menu from top to have white text color.

Comment: `#000` IS black. If you want white, that's `#fff`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this in your CSS:

```
.classic-menu .menu-item a {
  color: #fff;
}

.mini .menu-item a {
    color: #000;
}
```

`.classic-menu` is basically the regular state of your menu (when the background is black)

`.mini-active` is basically when the mini menu is activated, this way you'll get black for the mini menu and white for the regular one.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Noup, text in main menu is still black. Need to be white on black background.

Comment: Didn't notice that you have mini-active always in the class, this is misleading coding, anyway, I updated my answer, this should work I just tried it.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

write this code for your main menu, I think this is your main menu class

```
.classic-menu .menu-item a
{
background-color:#000;
color:#fff;
}
```

write this code for your sticky menu or scroll menu class, i don't know your scroll menu class

```
{
background-color:#fff;
color:#000;
}
```

to override this class use !important